# How to write an if statement in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have an if statement with two conditions and an `OR` operator between them, it evaluates to be true after only one condition.

because I used the `||` operator it checks the first condition and if it is true it will go into the if statement without checking the second one.

```
if (checkPassword() == true || checkUserName() == true)
    event.preventDefault();
```

I expect it to go into the `checkUserName()` function because there are crucial things in it that needs to be done, I can do it the long way but it will be cool if there is a way to make the if statement check the second condition even though it has the `||` operator and that's how programming works ( as far as I know)

Comment: Why not just use `&&` if you require both to be run?

Comment: Did you try `&&` instead of `||` so that both have to be true?

Comment: Why not assign the return values to two variables and then do `if (a || b)`? But functions with side effects are just bad functional programming.

Comment: If the first operand of `||` is true, there is no point in evaluating the second operand since it won't affect the result. Therefore it is skipped. If you want both to evaluate, then do `passwordResult = checkPassword(); usernameResult = checkUserName(); if( passwordResult || usernameResult) ...`

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I have done what you've offered before, but I wanted to find a more encapsulated way to do it, and also learn something on the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could defer the evaluation by collecting the values of the call.

And then look with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/) as callback if some value is truthy.

```
if ([checkPassword(), checkUserName()].some(Boolean)) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -3):

OR logical operator needs only one input to be true.

AND logical operator needs all inputs to be true.

Here are examples of two inputs:

`0` is false, `1` is true.

OR

```
0 0 | 0
0 1 | 1
1 0 | 1
1 1 | 1
```

AND

```
0 0 | 0
0 1 | 0
1 0 | 0
1 1 | 1
```